# How to detect whether specific value contains in MySQL table windows

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I have data structure like:

```
id      property_id     status      tran_id      as_of
1       1               sold        1111         2015-04-01    
2       1               listed      1111         2015-01-05
3       1               pending     1111         2015-01-02

7       2               listed      2211         2014-09-01
8       2               delisted    2211         2014-06-01
9       2               listed      2211         2014-04-01
10      2               delisted    2211         2014-01-01
11      2               sold        2211         2010-01-01

12      3               sold        6661         2015-08-01    
13      3               pending     6661         2015-04-05
14      3               listed      6661         2015-04-01
...
```

What I want is to detect whether specific property was sold (i.e. last status when `order by as_of asc` is not `sold`). So, for my case property 1 and 3 is sold and 2 isn't. I know how to do it using `OVER()` and `PARTITION BY()` from MS SQL Server, but now I am working with MySQL and I am totally stuck on it (I don't know MySQL as well as MSSQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last status for each property by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'sold' then 1 else 0 end) as is_sold
from t
where t.as_of = (select max(t2.as_of)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.property_id = t.property_id
                );
```

If you have a large amount of data, then an index on `t(property_id, date)` is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, with minor adjustments this query is what I am looking for!

Comment: And the adjustments were?

Comment: I think the OPs column was `as_of` where as this query has used `date` @juergend

Comment: @juergend I store descriptive names of status in lookup table, so I joined it read status string from it.